# how to check package dependancies in mac

Tags: macos, dependencies, osx-lion

I'm using OS X Lion (10.7.2).

I installed homebrew. it's easy to install package from homebrew. But I want to check package dependancies like below.

```
$ apt-cache depends package_name
```

or

```
$ apt-cache rdepend package_name
```

homebrew can check pakcage dependancies?

Are there the package management systems which can check package dependancies?

Answer (score 0):

[MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) does:

```
$ port dependents python27
mercurial depends on python27
py27-appscript depends on python27
py27-crypto depends on python27

$ port deps python27
Full Name: python27 @2.7.2_2+universal
Library Dependencies: gettext, zlib, openssl, sqlite3, db46, ncurses, gdbm, bzip2, libedit
Runtime Dependencies: python_select
```